# Dimmed headlights stopped working on Corsa B

Tags: lights

Driving along the freeway one night, my headlights stopped working.

I had been flicking between brights and dims for a while and then suddenly the dims just didn't come on.

I had to drive with my brights on until I got to my destination.

Question is, is the indicator/brights stalk a good place to start?

The other possible source of the fault is at the light switch which is on the dash itself, as opposed to the steering column.

Answer (score 1):

No, the best place to start is with a wiring diagram.

***Warning: If you decide to disassemble the steering column, disconnect your battery first. The airbag in the steering wheel can kill you if you cross the wrong wires.***

See the (awful, blurry) wiring diagram below from https://www.opeltech.org/cman-727.html . This diagram allegedly applies to all Corsa B models from 1990 onward. The low and high beam headlights in this diagram are marked E7, E8, E9 and E10 at the bottom of the diagram.

Selection between the two sets of lights is controlled by relay S5.2 which in turn is energized through the hi-lo switch in the steering column stalk. So find that relay and verify that it is working. You should find it either under the hood in a fuse / relay box or in the passenger compartment in a fuse / relay box somewhere near the driver's knees. Energizing the coil should alternate continuity between two of the terminals and a third terminal. The diagram is too blurry to be sure of the terminal numbers.

You can also check fuses 5 and 6, which are for the lo beams. (Fuses 4 and 5 are for hi beams.) The fuses are not likely blown, as your lo beams both failed at the same time and the relay is a more likely reason.

If the relay checks out and the fuses are OK, then you might look at the hi-lo switch in the stalk as a last resort.

[image: e]

NOTE: You have verified that the low-beam filaments of your headlight bulbs are not burned out, right? Use an ohmmeter or continuity tester and don't touch the bulb with bare fingers (assuming a quartz bulb) or your fingerprints will char and shorten the life of the bulb.